# Как добавить в начало массива элемент с ключом?

Tags: php

Чтобы не изменялись все ключи массива, как, например, с использованием `array_unshift`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сложение массивов:

```
$arr = array('a'=>'abc', 'b'=>'def'); // исходный
$add = array('c'=>'ghi'); // добавляемый
$arr = $add + $arr; // Складываем
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [c] => ghi
    [a] => abc
    [b] => def
)
```

P.S. Кстати, array_merge() тоже вполне нормально работает:

```
$arr = array_merge($add, $arr); // результат тот же
```